# How do you remove html files from Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Example:

I have three html files in firebase hosting:

1. index.html
2. test1.html
3. test2.html

Question:

How to remove html files test1.html ? I was confused to remove that, 
whether to set the json file firebase.json or there are other ways?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Delete those files and run `firebase deploy`. Doesn't that work?

Comment: ok thanks, that's work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on how much you want to remove, you have a couple options:

**Remove a file**

To remove a single file, delete it locally and re-deploy.

```
$ rm public/foo.html
$ firebase deploy
```

**Disable hosting**

If you want to remove an entire site on Firebase hosting, you can [disable hosting entirely](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#hosting_commands).

```
$ firebase hosting:disable
? Are you sure you want to disable Firebase Hosting?
  This will immediately make your site inaccessible! Yes
✔  Hosting has been disabled for example-firebase. Deploy a new version to re-enable.
```