# how to delete file and folder in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

i just deploy my file into Firebase Hosting. But, how to delete file in Firebase Hosting ?. As far as i know, Firebase just give me basic CLI usage like `Firebase serve` and `Firebase deploy`, but how to delete file and folder ? My question is not how to disable Firebase Hosting, but how to delete file and folder inside Firebase Hosting.

Comment: hai @Grimthorr, it's different question, i want to delete file and folder, not disable my firebase hosting.

Comment: Oh, sorry - anything not in the "app" directory when you run `firebase deploy` will not be deployed to Firebase Hosting, so simply delete the file/folder from your local source and push using `firebase deploy`.

Comment: I selected the wrong duplicate - it's actually answered here: [How do you remove html files from Firebase Hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39202179).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to just delete a folder from Firebase Hosting. You'll have to redeploy your site.

1. Remove the folder from your local system
2. Redeploy the site

With those steps you'll have a deployed site without the folder in question.